# What kind of Iris is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, irises

If it actually is an Iris, that is.

I had no idea we had this plant and I had subconsciously grouped it under the non-flowering section. Imagine my surprise when it bloomed all of a sudden!

After multiple head scratches and failed googling attempts, I gave up and turned to you, good people of this gardening site, to help me on this quest.

[image: The flower]

[image: Side View]

[image: Two of these!]

[image: The leaves]

Comment: Would you like to [edit] your post with a few details about where the plant is growing? Even if it’s not native, some information about the conditions and climate are helpful.

Comment: I’m not sure where I got it from. But I live in South India, so I could have mentioned it thrives in tropical climate. Someone was able to figure it out anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is *Neomarica gracilis*, see here for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimezia#/media/File:Neomarica_gracilis_3.JPG).

Comment: Thanks! Does it usually take this long to flower?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know how long they take to flower normally, I never had these beauties myself. Your flowers and plants look like they are in good shape, keep up the good work!